# Unable to resume Activity null pointer exception on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing google map draw route between my location and destination location.

I am getting null pointer exception on tried to use my current location by default where ever I move.

In below code I have pointed out the error line.

**Stacktrace:**

```
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.prashant.adesara.googlemapv2/com.prashant.adesara.googlemapv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at com.prashant.adesara.googlemapv2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:97)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
08-21 01:38:23.040: E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    ... 12 more
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
double startLatitude;
double startLongitude;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

LatLng start;

LocationManager lm;
Location location;

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);  --->97th Line

        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        start = new LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude);

        //  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);

        final TextView txtDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeed);
        new Routing(getParent(), mMap, txtDistance).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, start, end);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get default user latitude and longitude location.that's why it throws null exception.

Comment: where is your  `LocationManager lm` initialized?

Comment: @Boss it is not initialized

Comment: So it will be `null`. No wonder you are getting a nullpointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its recommended to find all your views inside your `onCreate` method.

Also initialize the `LocationManager`

Do this in your `onCreate`

```
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    txtDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeed);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

And in `onResume()`

```
    if (Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);  

        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        start = new LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude);

        //  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);

        new Routing(getParent(), mMap, txtDistance).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, start, end);
    }
```